# I can't input values higher than 9 into this

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I think this works perfectly when I input values lower than 9. But whenever I input a value higher than 9, program throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I cant figure out which causes this problem. Can someone simply explain me this problem and what is the solution for this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] twoDAarray = new int[3][3];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter values: ");
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            twoDAarray[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(checkLoShuSquare( twoDAarray ));
}

public static boolean checkLoShuSquare( int[][] twoDAarray ) {
    boolean[] isUnique = new boolean[twoDAarray.length*twoDAarray[0].length+1];
    for ( int i = 0; i < twoDAarray.length; i++ ) {
       for ( int j = 0; j < twoDAarray[0].length; j++ ) {
         if ( isUnique[twoDAarray[i][j]] ){
            return false;
         }
         isUnique[twoDAarray[i][j]] = true;
       }
    }

    int[] lessThan9 = new int[twoDAarray.length*twoDAarray[0].length+1];
    for ( int i = 0; i < twoDAarray.length; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < twoDAarray[0].length; j++ ) {
            if (lessThan9[twoDAarray[i][j]] <= 9){
                return true;
            }
    }
  }
    return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: on which line is that exception thrown?

Comment: `isUnique[twoDAarray[i][j]] = true;` will cause a problem if the number is > 9.

Comment: The problem is lessThan9[twoDAarray[i][j]] <= 9 because the last index of lessThan9 is 9 so bigger than 9 will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @Stultuske  
    if ( isUnique[twoDAarray[i][j]] ){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `isUnique` array has size 10, instead it should be sized by the largest integer that has been inserted by the user.

Of course, there are better ways to check for duplicate numbers of arbitrary size, like using a `Set<Integer>`.

Comment: isn't array size of ```isUnique``` 7 as it is 2 * 3 + 1